# python and pytest: equivalent of the @classmethod but for the entire module

Tags: python

I am using pytest to run `unittest.TestCase` classes, each of these classes is running certain experiments. I did break them down in different classes because the teardown and setup phase is different.

When I run pytest calling the module that contain these classes, they all run at the same time; which is what I want.

The problem is that I have some `@classmethod` which I use to trigger the output on a file of the results; which means that since I have 2 classes, I get 2 reports.

Is there an equivalent for a module, that execute when all the `unittests.TestCase` classes has been executed? So I can print one report with all the data together, instead of 2 separate ones

Comment: See [Module level setup/teardown](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html#module-level-setup-teardown)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking into Python docs and didn't think to go to look into pytest docs. Giving it a try now